# in sql sum of numbers in a column which start with say '55' and want to group them in 1 row

Tags: sql, group-by, row

I want sum of all numbers from a column which start with say '55' and want to group them together in 1 row. So, all the numbers starting with 55 in that column should be grouped in 1 row.

Comment: select left(abc, 2) , sum(requested_amount),
from table 
group by abc

Comment: @AllanChua this wont give me right answer as i am getting list of numbers which start with 55 but not able to group them together in 1 row

Comment: it's already grouped in one row SUM() is an aggregate function. it add up every row that passed the filter. did you already tried it on your sql server?

Comment: please see my query. I want sum of amount column but want to group with column which has number starting with 55 only. so number which starts with 55 in abc column should be grouped and sum of amount should be populated in another column. eg. 1st column = 55, 2nd column = $3746123746372945

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Column_NAME), SUBSTRING(CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 0, 2)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY SUM(Column_NAME), SUBSTRING(CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 0, 2)
```